# Show qty for tier_price in product list

Tags: magento

I need to show qty field for tier_price near regular price in product list (highest qty for lowest tier_price). Now $_product->getTierPrice() in product list gives me array(1) with 'tier_price'=>xxx and 'qty'=>1 (where xxx is lowest of my tier prices). Is it possible to get qty for tier_price in product list?

PS. In product view I can see array of tier prices with $_product->getTierPrice().

Magento CE 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code in list.phtml or in view.phtml to show tier prices for each quantity.

```
$attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');
$currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
$symbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())->getSymbol();
if ($attribute) {
    $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($_product);
    $tierPrices = $_product->getTierPrice();

    foreach($tierPrices as $tierPrice)
    {
    ?>
    <span class="priceqty"><?php echo '+'.round($tierPrice["price_qty"], 0);?></span><br>
    <span class="pricetitle"><?php echo $symbol.number_format($tierPrice["price"], 2, '.', '');?></span>
<?php  
    } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a Magento way:

```
 $attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('tier_price');

    if ($attribute) {
       $attribute->getBackend()->afterLoad($_product);
       $tierPrices = $_product->getTierPrice();
    }
```

From `/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Price.php` `getTierPrice()`

I have tested on Magento 1.4.0.2 (it should work also on other version ) on category pages and it works

In case you want to do it with SQL look here:
[Magento: Display tier prices at category listing page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928433/magento-display-tier-prices-at-category-listing-page/19929675#19929675)